# How to identify top node references in GMF editors

Tags: model, editor, xsd, limits, eclipse-gmf

I'm developing a graphical editor using Eclipse GMF.The model is developed from a xml schema.

According to the schema A,B,C,D elements are included in element E and E is included in element F.I have map F for the canvas in model declarations.

I'm getting errors when I try to develop editor from this schema. The elements A,B,C,D,E are not displayed correctly in the pallet.

Isn't it possible to consider  A,B,C,D  as top nodes references?
If "E" is the only top node, how am I supposed to represent A,B,C,D?

To get the necessary functionality, I need to change the schema. But I don't want to do it as I need to save designs in XML according to that schema.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to develop the model as mentioned above. But it doesn't work. 
So I changed the model as below.

A,B,C,D elements are included in element E and A,B,C,D,E elements are included in element F.

Although it is not exactly what I wanted, it works.